# Cryptotext in Unicode from Byte Array Seems to Contain Invalid Characters

Tags: c#, encryption, unicode, character-encoding, textview

My encryption application (written in C# & GTK# and using Rijndeal) takes a string from a textview to encrypt, and returns the result in a Byte array. I then use Encoding.Unicode.GetString() to convert it to a string, but my output doesn't look right, it seems to contain invalid characters: `zźr[�  ��ā�֖�Z�_����
W��h�.

I'm assuming that the encoding for the textview is not Unicode, but ASCII doesn't work either. How can I ensure that the output is not invalid? Or is my approach wrong to begin with?

I'm new to C# and not very experienced with programming in general (I have decent skill in PHP and know a little JavaScript, but that's about it) so if you could baby-down your answers it would be much appreciated.

Thank you in advance for taking the time to assist me.

Comment: By the way, the output when I convert the byte array to ASCII is: ??????3q??'?????e1?d???G?^u^BH

Comment: Not really, that ? is inserted by the encoding method to represent characters it - uh - cannot represent in ASCII. ASCII is 7 bits out of a byte, and the output of encryption is generally all 8 bits out of a byte (or, for those understanding the historical difference, out of an octet).

Comment: I'm aware of that, I'm just pointing out that the output can't properly be represented by ASCII. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While every string can be represented as a sequence of bytes using UTF-16, not every sequence of bytes represents a UTF-16 encoded string. Especially if the sequence of bytes is the result of an encryption process.

You can use the [Convert.ToBase64String Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524.aspx) to convert the sequence of bytes to a [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) string.